# Run .sql script for a particular database

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker

I'm using Postgres's official Docker image. I have a script under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` that creates two different databases for me. I want to initialize the table schemas for a particular database using a `.sql` file. The `.sql` file is very simply and looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
)
```

What I would like this to do is something like this (I'm making up this syntax):

```sql
FOR database_a AS username

CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE bar (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
)
```

Is this possible? Seems like a common feature but I can't find any information on it.

Comment: You cannot do that in SQL. Write a shell script or `psql` script for that.